# How to share variables between two django class?

Tags: python, django

I have two `django` class **A** and **B**. Both in the same django App folder（But they are in different files）. Now I want class **B** can access to class **A** variable.

```
Class A:
 def generate(self):
   url = "i want access to this variable from Class B"


Class B:
 def get(self):
  # get url variable and do something
```

What should I do to implement it？

Answer (score 3):

You should first instantiate an `A` instance, then return the `url` from `generate` function, then feed the return value to `get` function in `B`:

```
Class A:
 def generate(self):
   url = "i want access to this variable from Class B"
   return url


Class B:
 def get(self, url):
  # get url variable and do something

# here's how you use it
a = A()
b = B()
b.get(a.generate())
```

See if that makes sense.

**Edit:**

If your `generate` function is set to stone, you could also elevate the `url` as class variable:

```
Class A:
 def generate(self):
   url = "i want access to this variable from Class B"
   self.foo_url = url

a = A()
b = B()
# call generate to get the foo_url as property of object a
a.generate()
b.get(a.foo_url)
```

Comment: In my case, That function cannot return data (There are a bunch of class are need to access it). So do you have other way to access to the variable?